# How to use Enum in Camel Route?

Tags: apache-camel

I have the following route:

```
.choise()
   .when()
      .simple("${body.messageType} == 105")
          .to(...)
   .when()
      .simple("${body.messageType} == 106")
          .to(...)
```

I want to use this enum to compare.

```
  package myPackage; 

  public enum Code {
     CODE_A("105"), 
     CODE_B("106")

     private String value;

    Code(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String value() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

I tried to do something like this, but it doesn't works..

```
.simple("${body.messageType} == ${type:myPackage.Code.CODE_A.value()}")
```

Any idea to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by doing the following:

```
.setHeader("codeA",constant(myPackage.Code.CODE_A.value())) 
.setHeader("codeB",constant(myPackage.Code.CODE_B.value())) 
.choise()
   .when()
      .simple("${body.messageType} == ${header.codeA}")
          .to(...)
   .when()
      .simple("${body.messageType} == ${header.codeB}")
          .to(...)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it's the only solution for simple as it doesn't allow to call method for enum type (at least without hacks)

Comment: Yes, it solves this particular issue but it's not the universal solution. It's fine when you have a couple of enum items, but when you have more items...

Answer (score 6):

According to http://camel.apache.org/simple.html you can use just

```
.simple("${body.messageType} == ${type:myPackage.Code.CODE_A}")
```

In example you have tried you are using

```
myPackage.Code.value()
```

not

```
myPackage.Code.CODE_A
```

Comment: Thanks, I fix it. I saw the documentation, but if I do that Camel compares against "CODE_A" not against 105.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it using Groovy expressions. Add `camel-groovy` to pom/gradle.

Use the following expression:

```
.when().groovy("body.messageType == myPackage.CODE_A.value()")
```

Comment: There is no other way to solve it? I would rather avoid groovy use in this case.

Answer (score 0):

My simple syntax looks like:

```
//one value
simple(String.format("${body.key} == '%1s'", Code.CODE_A.value())
// multiple values using 'in' operator
simple(String.format("${body.key} in '%1s,%2s'", Code.CODE_A.value(), Code.CODE_B.value())
```

I like the use of String.format() instead of concatenating all parts as it makes the simple statement more readable